# OBJ import creates messy geometry, what is going wrong?

Tags: export, import, obj, collada

I'm having problems importing a public source file containing 3D buildings in The Netherlands into our 3D BIM software ArchiCAD. The website (https://3dbag.nl/en/viewer) offers 3 types of files, including OBJ-files. The proposed workaround is to import the OBJ-file into Blender and export a Collada file for use in ArchiCAD. However, when I open the Collada (.dae) file in ArchiCAD the geometry is all messed up and doesn't look like the preview in the website's viewer anymore. Is there a way to import the OBJ-file into Blender and retain the exact geometry that should be in the file?

Another method we have tried is using the CityJSON-file and importing/exporting through QGIS, but that resulted in a non-solid wireframe. This wireframe did have the correct geometry though...

Another method was using a plugin called Modelport which imports OBJ-files directly into ArchiCAD. This works, using the same OBJ-file, and gives the correct geometry. However, this plugin is not open source and costs quiete a bit.

The above trials show that the correct and accurate geometry IS included in the OBJ-file but somehow gets distorted while importing into Blender. I know the software is called Blender but I would expect it to be possible to import a 3D file 'unblended'.

If anyone has any idea how to fix this it would be very much appreciated!

The file I'm currently looking for is this one: https://3dbag.nl/en/download?tid=1024

Below are screenshots of the 3D buildings in the online viewer on the left, and the final 3D model imported into ArchiCAD (through Blender) on the right.

[image: 3D BAG viewer (left) and ArchiCAD (right)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a floating point precision problem. Then you import objects in Blender, do the following (imported objects should be selected):

1. reset object centers by pressing Object → Set Origin → Origin to Geometry
2. reset position:

Look at transforms:

[image]

Press <kbd>G</kbd>, then  <kbd>X</kbd> and subtract the X position by pressing the same number:

[image]

Do the same for Z axis. If you do everything right, objects will appear on the screen:

[image]

Objects, that are close to scene origin, are more likely to have less precision problems. Proceed with export.

Comment: YES! Thank you for this, this works! Now I'll try to clean up the triangulation some more and try to find a way to ungroup this model so I can export a selection to ArchiCAD.